# Python best way to document imported module version in scripts

Tags: python, module, documentation, pep

What is the best way or PEP convention to document the versions of **imported modules** in single python scripts? Sometimes I have to use older scripts that does not run because of module incompatibility (for example the script was written using pandas 0.15.0 and matplotlib 1.3.0, and now I use pandas 0.18.1 and matplotlib 1.5.1). It would be great for example if the first part of the script would contain pandas (and other imported module's) version in comment, like:

```
"""my_script_version = '0.0.1'
pandas_version = '0.15.0'
matplotlib_version = '1.3.0'
other_imported_module_version = 'x.y.z'
"""
```

Or is there any official way to do this? Something like using some metadatas?

```
__version__ = '0.0.1'
__date__ = '2016-06-06'
__author__ = 'ragesz'

__pandas_version__ = '0.15.0'
__matplotlib_version__ = '1.3.0'
__other_imported_module_version__ = 'x.y.z'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PEP 518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/) has been accepted recently regarding your question.

Dependencies has to be stored in a specific file *`pyproject.toml`*

```
[build-system]
# Minimum requirements for the build system to execute.
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel"]  # PEP 508 specifications.
```

[PEP 508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/) specify syntax for the requirements.

Comment: Thank you! I know that I can get for example `pd.__version__` for pandas (and for any other modules). What I don't know that what the coding style is to insert the version number into my python script. Place in a comment? Or store in a variable? Or any other way?

Comment: Just declare i.e. : `__version__ = '0.1.0'` in your module (following specification in https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/ )

Comment: I edited and updated my question for better understanding (I want to "save" the versions of imported modules, not my script version).

Comment: Thank you again for your older and final answer. Finally I wrote a function that returns with a dictionary containing the imported but not core module names and versions plus some system information (about os, cpu, compiler). I can copy-paste its result into my script in comment or passing to a `__<abc>__` variable or I can save it to a separate (toml or txt) file.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to add information on your script is whit metadata, for example:

```
__version__="1.0.2"
__appname__="name script"
__author__="author"
__description__="short description"
__long_description__="long description for your script"
__author_email__="author@gmail.com"
```